# spark - Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, maven-assembly-plugin

SOLVED:
prop.setProperty("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") this line must be added to the connection properties.

I'm trying to lunch a spark job in local. I created a jar with dependencies by maven.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.agildata</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-rdd-dataframe-dataset</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>    
        <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.4.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
        <spark.version>1.6.0</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>example.dataframe.ScalaDataFrameExample</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I run the `mvn package` command and the build is succesfull. After i try to run the job like this way: `GMAC:bin gabor_dev$ sh spark-submit --class example.dataframe.ScalaDataFrameExample  --master spark://QGMAC.local:7077 /Users/gabor_dev/IdeaProjects/dataframe/target/spark-rdd-dataframe-dataset-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` but it throws this: `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`

Full error message:

```
16/07/08 13:09:22 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createConnectionFactory(JdbcUtils.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at example.dataframe.ScalaDataFrameExample$.main(ScalaDataFrameExample.scala:30)
    at example.dataframe.ScalaDataFrameExample.main(ScalaDataFrameExample.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
16/07/08 13:09:22 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Interest thing that if i build this way inside the IntelliJ IDEA nested console: `mvn package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=example.dataframe.ScalaDataFrameExample` it's running, and there is no error.

This is the relevant scala code part:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xx:1526:SIDNAME"

    val prop = new java.util.Properties

      prop.setProperty("user" , "usertst")
      prop.setProperty("password" , "usertst")

      val people = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url,"table_name",prop)

      people.show()
```

I checked my jar file, and it containst all dependencies. Can anybody help me how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: copy-paste of the relevant section of the error?

Comment: copied. check please the question.

Comment: and in IntelliJIdea works, correct? Are you doing this on a cluster or in local?

Comment: local. And yes, IletlliJIdea  works correct. The db connect works and people.show method print the table to the nested console..

Comment: would you try to add the `.setMaster("local[2]")` to the SparkConf?

Comment: ohh sorry, i'm newbie in this topic.. where can i find it ?

Comment: val sc = new SparkContext(conf).setMaster("local[2]")  The first line of your code

Comment: val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Example")
      .setMaster("local[2]")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf) This is how it's look like.. the same error occured.. :(

Comment: but of course when i build it i can see the table data in the IDEA nested console.. :)

Comment: Hmmm... Do you simply build the jar file with all the dependencies and then launch it?

Comment: yes. like this: mvn package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=example.dataframe.ScalaDataFrameExample and then try to run on spark like this: 
sh spark-submit --class example.dataframe.ScalaDataFrameExample  --master spark://QGMAC.local:7077 /Users/gabor_dev/IdeaProjects/dataframe/target/spark-rdd-dataframe-dataset-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: ! your error is of the kind java.sql.SQLException, I was investigating on the Spark Driver; silly me! You have to configure the jdbc driver: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089900/jdbc-driver-not-found-on-submitting-to-yarn-from-spark or put it in the code manually like: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm where you put the first registration lines in the code BEFORE the spark application

Comment: this was the solution: i have to add this to the connection properties:  prop.setProperty("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

Comment: Either I write the answer or you answer to yourself for future reference: this may be a more common problem than we think!

Comment: please write, you helped me.. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, the missing driver is the JDBC one and you have to add it to the SparkSQL configuration. You either do it in the application submit, as specified [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089900/jdbc-driver-not-found-on-submitting-to-yarn-from-spark), or you do it through your Properties object, as you did, with this line:

```
prop.setProperty("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you will connect to postgresql using spark.

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().
            appName("dky").
            master("local[*]").
            getOrCreate();

    Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.WARN);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("user", "your user name");
    properties.put("password", "your password");

    Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = sparkSession.read().option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
            .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "your table name along with schema name", properties);
    jdbcDF.show();
```